# Does it still help to flag off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, review

Today, I again bumped into

> Thank you for reviewing 20 first posts today; come back in 4 hours to continue reviewing.

Given the enormous influx of off-topic questions, is it still helpful that I flag these? Since I have 'only' a lowly 2276 rep, my flag is just a drop in a bucket needing additional drops to become effective.

I imagine that users with more rep can just hammer blatantly off-topic questions into oblivion with a few clicks. In that case my tiny flags would not help much.

---

**Update 8 november 2018**

Sorry people, I stop all my 'moderation' activities on this site and will delete my profile.
The mess about pronouns and Monica makes me [no longer want to contribute to maintenance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/334704/189029).

Good luck with keeping the incoming off topic questions down.

Comment: Seeing that not even I can keep up with hammering and miss an estimated 30% I'd say yes: pushing it into the review queue definitely helps. Wish you had 3k+ so you could push into the general review queue for other 3k+ users to join up… We'll try to hammer away in parallel, with Glorfindel having given us another tool so speed that up – but every drop helps!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it definitely helps!

Your flags push the posts into the review queues, where they are likely to (eventually) get the further processing they require.

I've personally noticed many helpful flags from you, and I appreciate them.